# How to get month name with year and list of years between two Date

Tags: ios, xcode, date, swift3, calendar

I want to get list of month names between two dates

> Date1 : 1/1/2016
>
> Date2 : 1/4/2017

```
Result should be : 
    January 2016 
    February 2016
    March 2016
    April 2016 To  April 2017
```

Comment: Your "Date2" is not a valid date. Did you mean to post "1/4/2017" instead?

Comment: yes it's 1/4/2017 @ducan

Comment: @user459460  is it solved now...?

Answer (score 4):

```
 //let startDateString:String  = "01/01/2017"
 //let endDateString:String = "04/01/2017"

 let startDateString:String  = "08/01/2016"
 let endDateString:String = "04/01/2018"

 let dateFormtter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

 let startDate = dateFormtter.date(from: startDateString)
 let endDate = dateFormtter.date(from: endDateString)

 var monthsStringArray = [String]()
 var monthsIntArray = [Int]()
 var monthsWithyear = [String]()
 dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MM"

 if let startYear: Int = startDate?.year(), let endYear = endDate?.year() {

        if let startMonth: Int = startDate?.month(), let endMonth: Int = endDate?.month() {
            for i in startYear...endYear {
                for j in (i == startYear ? startMonth : 1)...(i < endYear ? 12 : endMonth) {
                    let monthTitle = dateFormtter.monthSymbols[j - 1]
                    monthsStringArray.append(monthTitle)
                    monthsIntArray.append(j)

                    let monthWithYear = "\(monthTitle) \(i)"
                    monthsWithyear.append(monthWithYear)
                }
            }
        }

 }

    print(monthsStringArray)
    print(monthsIntArray)
    print(monthsWithyear)


//-------
extension Date {

    func month() -> Int {
        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
        return month
    }

    func year() -> Int {
      let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
      return year
   }
}
```

> **Result:**
>   
> *for dates between "01/01/2017" to "04/01/2017"*
>   
> monthsStringArray = ["January", "February", "March", "April"]
>   
> monthsIntArray = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>   
> monthsWithyear = ["January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017", "April 2017"]
>   
> *for dates between "08/01/2016" to "04/01/2018"*
>   
> monthsWithyear = ["August 2016", "September 2016", "October 2016", "November 2016", "December 2016", "January 2017", "February 2017", "March 2017", "April 2017", "May 2017", "June 2017", "July 2017", "August 2017", "September 2017", "October 2017", "November 2017", "December 2017", "January 2018", "February 2018", "March 2018", "April 2018"]

Comment: showing error "can not call value of non-function type int"  in this line if let startMonth: Int = startDate?.month(), let endMonth: Int = endDate?.month()

Comment: Ok now working and if i pass January thn it is possible to get number of month

Comment: i want month with year between two dates

Comment: it's showing all the months of 2016 and 2017 , i want  month name and year  between two dates only

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to get a list of years between two dates.

```
func getYear(){
    let startDateString:String  = "05/21/2014"
    let endDateString:String = "05/21/2017"

    let dateFormtter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"

    let startDate = dateFormtter.date(from: startDateString)
    let endDate = dateFormtter.date(from: endDateString)

    var arrYears = [String]()
    dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MM"

    if let startYear: Int = startDate?.year(), let endYear = endDate?.year() {
        for i in startYear...endYear {
            let monthWithYear = "\(i)"
            arrYears.append(monthWithYear)
        }
    }
}

extension Date {
   func Year() -> Int {
        let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
        return year
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var monthsList = [String]()
    let fmt = DateFormatter()
    let startingMonthNumber:Int  = 0
    let endingMonthNumber:Int  = 3

    for i in startingMonthNumber..<endingMonthNumber {
        let monthName = fmt.monthSymbols[i]
        monthsList.append(monthName)
    }

    print(monthsList) //["January", "February", "March"]
```

Comment: i want list of month between two date , starting date could be any date less than current today date

Comment: @user459460 get the month MM value from date string & replace with startingMonthNumber,endingMonthNumber values.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with the method `enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:matchingPolicy:)` of `Calendar`to enumerate dates very efficiently based on `DateComponents`

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let dateFormtter = DateFormatter()
dateFormtter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

// create the start and end dates from the strings
let startDate = dateFormtter.date(from: "1/1/2016")!
let endDate = dateFormtter.date(from: "1/4/2017")!
// set the date format to the destination format
dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MMMM yyyy"

// Create the matching conponent : day 1 of each month
let components = DateComponents(day: 1)
// The variable result will contain the array of month names,
var result = [dateFormtter.string(from: startDate)]

// this particular method of Calendar enumerates each date matching the components
calendar.enumerateDates(startingAfter: startDate, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .nextTime) { (date, strict, stop) in
    result.append(dateFormtter.string(from: date!))
    // exit the enumeration if the end date is reached
    if date! >= endDate { stop = true }
}

print(result)
```

Comment: is it possible to get results of month to specific years results.month to result.Year ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Making the 'Krunal' answer a little more clean:

```
enum monthYearArrayType {
    case monthsStringArray
    case monthsIntArray
    case monthsWithyear
    case monthsWithyearExceptCurrent
}

func monthsBetweenDates(startDate: Date?, endDate: Date?, displayType: monthYearArrayType) -> Array<Any> {
    let dateFormtter = DateFormatter()

    var monthsStringArray = [String]()
    var monthsIntArray = [Int]()
    var monthsWithyear = [String]()
    var monthsWithyearExceptCurrent = [String]()
    dateFormtter.dateFormat = "MM"

    if let startYear: Int = startDate?.year(), let endYear = endDate?.year() {

        if let startMonth: Int = startDate?.month(), let endMonth: Int = endDate?.month() {
            for i in startYear...endYear {
                for j in (i == startYear ? startMonth : 1)...(i < endYear ? 12 : endMonth) {
                    let monthTitle = dateFormtter.monthSymbols[j - 1]
                    monthsStringArray.append(monthTitle)
                    monthsIntArray.append(j)

                    let monthWithYear = "\(monthTitle) \(i)"
                    monthsWithyear.append(monthWithYear)

                    if(i == Date().year()) {
                        monthsWithyearExceptCurrent.append(monthTitle)
                    } else {
                        monthsWithyearExceptCurrent.append(monthWithYear)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    switch displayType {
    case .monthsWithyear:
        return monthsWithyear
    case .monthsWithyearExceptCurrent:
        return monthsWithyearExceptCurrent
    case .monthsStringArray:
        return monthsStringArray
    case .monthsIntArray:
        return monthsIntArray
    }
}


extension Date {
    func month() -> Int {
        let month = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
        return month
    }

    func year() -> Int {
        let year = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: self)
        return year
    }
}
```