# Get list of months between dates

Tags: swift, nsdate, swift4, dateformatter

I have two dates i.e. **2/02/2016** & **19/03/2018**

i am trying to fetch months & year between this dates as

*output should be*

> Feb 2016, Mar 2016 ......and so on.... Jan 2018, Feb 2018, Mar 2018.

Tried month Gap code -

```
  let date1 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2016, month: 2, day: 2).date!
  let date2 = DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: 2018, month: 3, day: 19).date!
  let monthGap = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.month], from: date1, to: date2)
  print("monthGap is \(String(describing: monthGap.month))")//prints monthGap is 25
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get month name with year and list of years between two Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522642/how-to-get-month-name-with-year-and-list-of-years-between-two-date)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a simple method that returns you the date and month in the format as you described above,

```
func getMonthAndYearBetween(from start: String, to end: String) -> [String] {
    let format = DateFormatter()
    format.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

    guard let startDate = format.date(from: start),
        let endDate = format.date(from: end) else {
            return []
    }

    let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
    let components = calendar.dateComponents(Set([.month]), from: startDate, to: endDate)

    var allDates: [String] = []
    let dateRangeFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateRangeFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM yyyy"

    for i in 0 ... components.month! {
        guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: i, to: startDate) else {
        continue
        }

        let formattedDate = dateRangeFormatter.string(from: date)
        allDates += [formattedDate]
    }
    return allDates
}
```

And you call it like,

```
getMonthAndYearBetween(from: "2/02/2016", to: "19/03/2018")
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

Based on Sandeep's answer, this `Date` static extension function takes `Date` objects for input & will return an array of `Date` objects sorted by month & year:

```
extension Date {
    
    static func getMonthAndYearBetween(from start: Date, to end: Date) -> [Date] {
        var allDates: [Date] = []
        guard start < end else { return allDates }
        
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let month = calendar.dateComponents([.month], from: start, to: end).month ?? 0
        
        for i in 0...month {
            if let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .month, value: i, to: start) {
                allDates.append(date)
            }
        }
        return allDates
    }
    
}
```